# FireBase pushing notification to android using raw TCPIP packets only

Tags: android, ios, tcp, m2m

In my project I need to push notification from my own developed M2M device to android phone/IOs app. This means I can only send data stream to known IP address and port, that's it.

Is this possible to do with FireBase ? If yes, can some one guide me what exactly I need to search for ? I am more hardware engineer, this would be my start in android/IOs programming

Thank you !

Searching how to implement idea at the moment, what would be easiest and most robust

Comment: It looks like where are not much info about this...